# Поиск url на странице - вывод, в случае отсутствия url

Tags: php

Вот наброски:

```
﻿<?php
$siteurl = file_get_contents('vse.txt'); //vse.txt -файл со списком url
$strok=preg_split("/[\n\r]+/s",$siteurl); //разделяем url'ы по переменным
$count = count($strok); //считаем количество url
$i = 0; //определяем начальный параметр
$get_site = file_get_contents('http://test.ru/'); // скачиваем страницу, где будем искать
while($count>$i) { //выполняем цикл столько раз, сколько у нас url
if(strpos($get_site, $strok[$i]) == false || strpos($get_site, $strok[$i]) == NULL) {  //если url не найден
echo $strok[$i]."<br>";  //вывести url, перевести строку
$i++; //переход на следующий url
} 
}
?>
```

Но у меня просто выводится содержание vse.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам исправился:

```
$siteurl = file_get_contents('vse.txt');
$siteurl = strtr($siteurl, array('http://' => ''));
$strok=preg_split("/[\n\r]+/s",$siteurl);
$count = count($strok);
$i = 0;
$get_site = file_get_contents('http://test.ru/');
while($count>$i) {
if(!preg_match(('|'.trim($strok[$i]).'|'), $get_site)) { 
echo trim($strok[$i])."<br>"; 
} 
$i++;
}
```